# Firebase Storage to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get an image that I have stored inside Firebase Storage inside an UIImageView.
I have the URL of the image saved inside Firebase Database for that user, but don't know how to grab it

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift/27517280#27517280

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make an action for it **this func opens the Photo carrier**

```
  @IBAction func selecFoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let imageController = UIImagePickerController()
            imageController.delegate = self
            imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
//you can also set animate to false 
            self.present(imageController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
```

this func selects the image and you can storage wherever you want

```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
// here you can preview the image you selected if that's the case 
        imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import FirebaseStorage

Storage.storage().reference(forURL: yourDownloadedURL).getData(maxSize: 1048576, completion: { (data, error) in

    guard let imageData = data, error == nil else {
        return
    }
    someImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

})
```

Obviously, handle errors as well as corrupted image data, by perhaps falling back to a default image (just because we have image data in hand does not guarantee it will render a perfect image), and use a maximum file size appropriate to your application.